# Accessing WAR files from an EJB archive inside EAR (migrating to JBoss 7 from 6)

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, war, ear

im currently migrating an existing SEAM 2 application from JBoss 6 to JBoss EAP 6.
 Everything works fine except one thing. I must read an HTML file packaged inside the WAR from an Service that is packaged inside the EJB archive.

I have the following depolyment structure:

- proj.ear

  - proj.war
  - proj.ejb

In JBoss 6 it was possible with:

> InputStream htmlContent =
>   Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
>   .getResourceAsStream("/proj.war/sample.html");

Is there a way to do the same thing with JBoss 7? I have already read about the possibility to use an
extra module. But in my opinion the proj.war is already an implicit module and i want to avoid
splitting HTML files accross different modules.

Thanks in advance

I have attached the EAR deployment descriptor.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">

    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="weld" />
        </exclude-subsystems>

        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.dom4j" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
            <module name="com.google.guava" />

            <module name="org.antlr" export="true" />
            <module name="asm.asm" export="true" />
            <module name="org.javassist" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="proj.war">
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="weld" />
        </exclude-subsystems>

        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>

        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: What kind of error messages do you get? FileNotFound?

Comment: The return value of getResourceAsStream() is always null.